# find 3d coordinates of pyramid peak from angles and base size

Tags: geometry

I have a strange geometric problem, and I cannot find a solution for it so far.

I have, effectively, constructed a pyramid, and need to find the coordinates of the peak. I have 4 angles: each one angle of the peak that makes up that face of the pyramid. I also have the dimensions of the base.

[image]

I wonder if there is a way to find the coordinates of the pyramid's peak. Rephrasing slightly, in my drawing, is there a way to find the coordinates of the origin point. There will be a few solutions I believe, is there a way to find even one?

Comment: It seems to me that your problem is overdetermined, because given the base (which is known) you want to find the apex (peak) which is determined by three coordinates, but you impose four conditions on the angles of the four faces.  If this was a tetrahedron instread (i.e. a triangular base) then there is equal number of unknowns as equations.

Comment: interesting, thank you! so the problem is, in a sense, easier with only 3 coordinates?